# Share nodes to Slack

Tags: social-network

i want to share link of post in social media i find module addtoAny and module social media for sharing poste butI didn't find to share post to slack.

Any help?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it asks to find, recommend, or suggest hosting providers, tools, modules, themes, distributions, books, tutorials, documentation, or other off-site resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two modules, I didn't try them myself and I'm not sure what is your use case:
[Drupal to Slack](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal_to_slack) and [Slack](https://www.drupal.org/project/slack). Are these provide the functionality you want?

---

### Update

Ok, there are other modules for adding share buttons like [Simple Addthis](https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_addthis) or the dev version of the original [Addthis Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/addthis/releases/8.x-4.x-dev)